# User Batch File Issues

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Ok a little background I am new to using batch files. I am trying to create a new user, assign to admin group and then demote the current user to a standard account. This is all local and will be done remotely. I have it working so the new user is created and added the admin account, but I need to get the current username and somehow call it in the last command. Below is what I have so far, please help.

```
net user "USERNAME" "PASSWORD" /add /comment:"COMMENT" /passwordchg:NO
wmic useraccount where "name='USERNAME'" set passwordexpires=FALSE
net localgroup administrators "USERNAME" /add
timeout /t 20 /nobreak 

wmic.exe /node:127.0.0.1 ComputerSystem Get Username

net localgroup administrators %username% /delete
```

Comment: Not sure what to tell you.  `net localgroup administrators %username% /delete` works for me...

Comment: The problem I have is this is being  done through GFI and the %username% variable comes up as the workstation name not the user. Is it possible to use the wmic command to write a variable then call that variable in the last command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In next code snippet, the `for` loops are:

- `%%a` to retrieve the username (in the second token, `%%b`)
- `%%c` to remove the ending carriage return in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` instead of common `0x0D0A`)

Note `_` leading underscore in `%_username%`: do not override system environment variable `%username%`

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (
  'wmic /node:127.0.0.1 ComputerSystem Get Username /value'
  ) do for /f "delims=" %%c in ("%%~b") do set "_username=%%c"

echo %_username%

net localgroup administrators %_username% /delete
```

Answer (score 0):

`wmic.exe /node:127.0.0.1 ComputerSystem Get Username > username.txt
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type username.txt') DO SET MYUSER=%%A
del username.txt
net localgroup test %MYUSER% /delete`

Comment: Obviously I don't have one tenth of the understanding of DOS batch as @JosefZ.  Wows!

Comment: @Dean If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.